# HP Proliant Gen 8 Server does not recognise any HDDs after removed from array

Tags: hp-proliant

I'm going rapidly mad here!

I had a 1TB drive show up as not working in its Raid 0 array and it seems to have affected my 6TB Raid 1 Array which was working. I took these drives out and put in 2 new 3TB drives to set up as a Raid 1 array. These showed up as not working (although they work fine in Windows) - so I removed them thinking that that would show up as "not assigned" but they disappeared.

NOW no drives show up at all in the 2 data drive bays. The SSD on port 5 ( DVD connection) works fine and all drives work in Windows.

I cannot resolve the "invisibility" of all the drives in the drive bays? Any suggestions please?  Thanks, Mel

Comment: What are you asking? Where are the details? What type of server is this? Why were you replacing disks? What does _"not working"_ mean?

Comment: Not working = red LED flashing on microserver with disc error as cause. Microserver gen 8 1610. Replacing discs (which were working OK until the first 1TB drive went down as it seemed to have disrupted the 6TB array when it failed (as data was being written at the time?)

Comment: I'm asking  if anybody knows how to get my HDDs to show up as unassigned in the Smart Storage Administrator - currently they are not visible.

Answer (score 1):

Well - cracked it - simple - you have to "clean" the HDD in DISKPART before reusing it. Then Microserver recognises it I had left the drive with a volume and formatted. In this state it is apparently ignored.

Mel